# Detecting first or second Mouse Button Release?

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine

I want to know how to detect if the user has released the mouse button the **first time**, **or the times after that**:

Pseudo-Code:

```
 if *first* (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
   {
       do something
   }

 if *second, third, fourth..etc.* (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
   {
       do something else
   }
```

I really have no idea on how to accomplish this. I'm sure it's pretty simple though!

Comment: Yeah, keep a counter or other variable to store that the first click has occurred.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm new to programming, I don't know how to do that sir! :)

Comment: Maybe start at a tutorial then? :) Keeping count in a variable is about the most basic things there is.

Answer (score 2):

This is only an idea, but you could do this using a flag variable, like this:

```
private static bool WasFirstTimeReleased = false;

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    if (!WasFirstTimeReleased)
    {
        WasFirstTimeRelease = true;
        //do your stuff for first time
    }
    else
    {
        //do your stuff for all other times
    }
}
```

Comment: As the OP didn't mention if he needs to track the number of clicks but rather simply whether or not it was the first click I'd say this is the best approach. No need to track an integer when a nice tiny little boolean will do :) Though, why static?

Comment: @sab669 I really don't see why people is suggesting a counter when the OP didn't specify that they needed to know the number of times the mouse was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have to remember somewhere how many times button was released. Just create field in yours class:

```
private int clicks = 0;
```

then:

```
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
   {
       if(clicks == 0)
       {
           // do something on first click
       }
       else
       {
           // do something on further click
       }

       clicks++;
   }
```

If the object where you store clicks counter is created each time you press mouse button then mark counter using static word.

Answer (score 0):

**Keep track of mouse clicks:**

```
int _leftUp;

void Update()
{
    var leftUp = Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0);
    if (leftUp) _leftUp++;

    // etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to accomplish this would be to use a counter to check the number of times the user has released the button.

```
private int releaseCounter = 0;
```

And then in an if statement:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
    releaseCounter++;

    //If you know on which release you want the code to be executed, 
    //replace the x with that number.
    if (releaseCounter == x) { 
        //your code here
    }

    //If you want the code to be executed at set intervals.
    //replace the x with the interval number.
    if(releaseCounter%x == 0) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Hope I helped.